# positive constant divided by a concave function, how to convexify this constraint?

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have following constraint in my optimization problem:

$0 \leq t \leq  \frac{S}{B \ R(p)}$

where $t,p$ are optimization variables and $S,B$ are positive constants. 
$R(p)$ is a concave function which is in the denominator, is there any way to make this constraint convex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From your constraint, it's clear $R$ is positive as well. Then,we have $$\frac1{R(p)}=\max_{\lambda>0}\left(2\lambda-\lambda^2R(p)\right)$$ and since $R$ is concave, that's the maximum of a set of convex functions in $p$, i.e. it's convex (for a proof, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373229/show-that-the-maximum-of-a-set-of-convex-functions-is-again-convex)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, when I try to implement it in the cvx it gives error of 
Invalid constraint: {real affine} <= {convex}
Do you have any idea to overcome this problem in cvx?
thanks in advance

Comment: Or maybe to convert the above mentioned constraint as a concave expression, then it can be solved by cvx

Comment: @Syed Sorry, I misunderstood your question: I showed $1/R(p)$ is a convex function, but you want a "convex constraint" satisfying the rather stringent conditions in your specific software, and couldn't be bothered to explain that. Good luck with your question.